# How to get variables from another script C#

Tags: c#, string, scripting

I am completely stuck, and I feel like it's a simple issue too. Basically, I have two strings `pubKey` and `privKey` in one script called `WalletGen.cs` and I want to display them in `Loader.cs`. In my search for an answer, all I could find is how to do it in Unity, which doesn't exactly help since I'm *not* using Unity.

Here is the code for `WalletGen.cs`

```
namespace scriptcoin
{
    public class WalletGen
    {
        static void WalletHash()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int seed = rnd.Next();

            byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(seed);
            byte[] pubData;
            byte[] privData;

            SHA384 pubHash = new SHA384Managed();
            pubData = pubHash.ComputeHash(data);
            pubData = pubHash.ComputeHash(pubData);
            seed = rnd.Next();
            SHA256 privHash = new SHA256Managed();
            privData = privHash.ComputeHash(data);

            string pubKey = Convert.ToBase64String(pubData);
            string privKey = Convert.ToBase64String(privData);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really have any specific code in `Loader.cs` since I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the connection between these two classes? are they independent?

Comment: @un-lucky They are separate scripts in the same VS solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of Loader.cs? What is the purpose of WalletGen.cs? Without context, there's way too many ways to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code stands you cannot access pubKey or privKey because they exist only in the scope of the method `WalletHash`.

To expose them you could return them from `WalletHash`, eg.

```
    public static Tuple<string, string> WalletHash()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int seed = rnd.Next();

        byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(seed);
        byte[] pubData;
        byte[] privData;

        SHA384 pubHash = new SHA384Managed();
        pubData = pubHash.ComputeHash(data);
        pubData = pubHash.ComputeHash(pubData);
        seed = rnd.Next();
        SHA256 privHash = new SHA256Managed();
        privData = privHash.ComputeHash(data);

        string pubKey = Convert.ToBase64String(pubData);
        string privKey = Convert.ToBase64String(privData);
        return new Tuple<string, string>(pubKey, privKey);
    }
```

Then in Loader you get the values back from `WalletHash` like this (assuming you're currently calling `WalletHash` from Loader.

```
Tuple<string, string> keys = WalletGen.WalletHash();
string pubKey = keys.Item1;
string privKey = keys.Item2;
```

Comment: The static method would also need to be more accessible (eg. public or internal)